# Intuitive way of understanding carrier mobility dependence with Fermi Level

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-transport

I want to understand how does the carrier mobility $\mu$ vary with $E_F/k_bT$ in semiconductors. Is there any intuitive way of understanding this problem, let's say in the degenerate or non-degenerate regime?